# How to pass a variable as a route parameter when accessing the route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, route-parameters

This does not work:

```
return redirect('/view-project-team/' . $projectRequest->id );
```

What is the right way to pass a variable into the route in this context?

Comment: and what's the error that you get?

Comment: you should name the route, then use `return redirect()->route('nameOfRoute', ['id' => 1]);`

Comment: As @DerekPollard said, you can generate url to named route. [Named Routes docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)

Comment: and how and where do you have name a route?

Comment: I did this `Route::get('/view-project-team/{project_request_id}', 'SinglePageController@viewProjectTeam')->name('viewProjectTeam');`and this      `return redirect()->route('viewTeamProject', ['project_request_id' => $projectRequest->id ]);` but now I get a 500 error

Answer (score 5):

As was said in comments you should use name of the route:

```
return redirect()->route('view.project.team', ['id' => $projectRequest->id]);
```

Names can be defined in your router:

```
Route::get('/view-project-team/{id}', 'YourController@yourHandler')->name('view.project.team');
```

Note that:

1. Dots in name of the route are not necessary (you could give any name).
2. `'id'` in `route()` call is refer to `{id}` in `Route::get()` call (names must match).

Comment: when I implement this I get a 200 status code on redirect. Why does that happen?

Comment: I don't know why is that, but calling `route()` method that way always return 200. If you need to specify another code, you can pass it as a third argument to `route()` call. Like `... ['id' => $projectRequest->id], 302);`.